# Javascript object set to another object is undefined

Tags: javascript, object, google-chrome-extension

For my chrome extension, I have a function called storeGroup that returns an object. However, in function storeTabsInfo, when I call storeGroup and set it equal to another object, the parts inside the object are undefined. The object is being populated correctly in storeGroup, so I'm not sure why it's undefined?

```
function storeTabsInfo(promptUser, group)
{
var tabGroup = {};

chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(currentWindow)
{
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(currentWindow.id, function(tabs)
    {
        /* gets each tab's name and url from an array of tabs and stores them into arrays*/
        var tabName = [];
        var tabUrl = [];
        var tabCount = 0;

        for (; tabCount < tabs.length; tabCount++)
        {
            tabName[tabCount] = tabs[tabCount].title;
            tabUrl[tabCount] = tabs[tabCount].url;
        }

        tabGroup = storeGroup(promptUser, group, tabName, tabUrl, tabCount);   // tabGroup does not store object correctly
        console.log("tabGroup: " + tabGroup.tabName);   // UNDEFINED
        chrome.storage.local.set(tabGroup);
    })
})
}

function storeGroup(promptUser, group, name, url, count)
{
var groupObject = {};
// current count of group
var groupCountValue = group.groupCount;

var groupName = "groupName" + groupCountValue;
groupObject[groupName] = promptUser;

var tabName = "tabName" + groupCountValue;
groupObject[tabName] = name;

var tabUrl = "tabUrl" + groupCountValue;
groupObject[tabUrl] = url;

var tabCount = "tabCount" + groupCountValue;
groupObject[tabCount] = count;

var groupCount = "groupCount" + groupCountValue;
groupObject[groupCount] = groupCountValue + 1;

// successfully shows parts of groupObject
console.log("Final group: " + groupObject[groupName] + " " + groupObject[tabName] + " " + groupObject[tabUrl] + " " + groupObject[tabCount] + " " + groupObject[groupCount]);
return groupObject;
}
```

Comment: Your `groupObject`  doesn't have a `tabname` property. When you try to access it `tabGroup.tabName` you get undefined. If `tabName` is a variable holding the property name you need to access it with `tabGroup[tabName]`

Comment: You should use all properties with their group counts because you created the `groupObject` dict with groupCounts so you should use them with their counts.

Comment: console.log("tabGroup: " + tabGroup.tabName);  will not work, because say group.groupCount were 1, then that property would be tabName1, not tabName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in the comment above you created the `groupObject` dict keys with the group count so you should use it again to access them or remove it, if you want to use it again although i think this isnt necessary so use:-

```
... ,tabGroup[tabName + group.groupCount]...
```

But if you want to get it easily as you wrote just write this code instead of your code:-

```
function storeGroup(promptUser, group, name, url, count)
{
var groupObject = {};
// current count of group

groupObject['groupName'] = promptUser;

groupObject['tabName'] = name;

groupObject['tabUrl'] = url;

groupObject['tabCount'] = count;

groupObject['groupCount'] = group.groupCount + 1;

// successfully shows parts of groupObject
console.log("Final group: " + groupObject['groupName'] + 
" " + groupObject['tabName'] + " " + groupObject['tabUrl'] + 
" " + groupObject['tabCount'] + " " + 
groupObject['groupCount']);
return groupObject;
}
```